# Notifying a moderator without flagging?

Tags: support, moderators, notifications, comment-replies

Does `@Mod` `@Moderators` etc work, or do I have to notify individually (`@Qiaochu @Willie @Zev @Mariano`, etc) if I seek moderator intervention?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Moderator intervention is invoked using the "flag" link, not a comment.

In addition, the @-notification only works if the user is already participating in the comment thread. If you just randomly `@Mariano` on a comment thread which he has not commented on, he will not received any notification whatsoever. (In other words, the @-notification is expressly for *comment responses* and **not** for summoning genies.)

Comment: +1 The summoning genies part really made me laugh.

Comment: What does this have to do with summoning genies? Afterall, the notifications are intended to clean up the site, not for the fulfillment of my personal wishes. Anyhow, thanks for the concise answer.

Comment: @kuch: it is a joke.